# How to read a nested list from a file?

Tags: python, split, nested-lists

I'm trying to read a nested list from file but with no success.

The list looks like this:

```
[14,[["sss","aaa"],"21a"],[[[2,3],"eee"],2423]]
```

When I read it from file I know that I need to split it, but am not sure which delimiter to use.

If I debug it for list from file and same list which is being assigned to during the compile time:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
      list_file = f.read().split(",[")

list_original = [14,[["sss","aaa"],"21a"],[[[2,3],"eee"],2423]]
```

I'm getting the following results (debug):

[image: results]

Comment: This looks like `json` - just use `json.load` against the filehandle to convert it to a python list.

Comment: `import json with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: res = json.loads(f.read())`

Comment: Note: if you are serializing Python objects, why not consider [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin could you please refer to a sample code?

Comment: @user17302 Do you mean for using `pickle`?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Yes, could you refer to examples of pickle code that read a file which has nested list? I tried with open('my_data') as f: print pickle.load(f), unfortunately, got errors.

Comment: @user17302 it would probably be best to ask another question with the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the *json* module very useful for this case as follows:

```
import json

with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
    print(j)
```

**Output:**

```
[14, [['sss', 'aaa'], '21a'], [[[2, 3], 'eee'], 2423]]
```